# Using ActiveRecord::Errors after object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Can I use `ActiveRecord::Errors` with an existing object?

I have an object `Bla` that is created in a simple way; it just receives a **name** and a **csv file**.

After this object is created, an asynchronous action is called via `sidekiq` and the **csv file** is processed to create the other attributes of the object `Bla`.

I'm not sure how to deal with exceptions that may be raised during the file processing. I'm thinking of add the errors to the `errors` object accessible for validations errors and provided by `ActiveRecord::Errors`. That way, errors would be available to be displayed in it's show view.

I've seen this object being used withing the object creation, and it's used to display errors on the form before object is commited to the database.

Can I use it to display errors that occured after its creation? Are those errors stored on db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails validation errors are **not** stored in the db.  They are intended to block db-writes; that is, they prevent you from writing invalid objects to the db.

Validation errors are only stored in the 'errors' attribute of your ActiveRecord object, and only retained as long as the variable is "alive", which in Rails is usually only as long as it takes to render the page that follows execution of the controller action.

I don't know much about `sidekiq`.  If it's running in a separate process from the Rails server, then the validation errors, being only in memory, won't be shared between the two.  Even if it's *not* a separate process, I'm pretty sure your validation-having variable will cease to exist when the async action terminates.

So I suspect your proposed approach isn't workable.  You may have to store those validation errors in a more persistent memory, so that errors found by `sidekiq` can be read by Rails or vice-versa.